# ¿Cómo accedo al segundo string de ClipData?

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

Estoy trabajando en una app con `'Drop & drag'`
y tengo mi clase  `MyTouchListener`
donde  lleno mi clip data de mi `imageview`:

```
ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("a","b");
```

y en mi clase  `MyDragListener`

```
public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:

                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:

                //solo me saca el primer elemento del clipData
                switch(event.getClipDescription().getLabel().toString()){
                    case "a": 
                    .
                    .
                    .
```

La pregunta es: **¿Cómo saco el segundo elemento de mi `clipData`?**

Comment: has probado con data.getItemAt(1) haciendolo dentro de un bucle for()

Comment: Cual es el segundo elemento? te refieres al texto?

Comment: me refiero al texto"b" del ejemplo ya que con el codigo que puse solo puedo sacar el primer texto "a"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El segundo valor dentro del objeto `ClipData` es el texto, puedes obtenerlo mediante este método:

```
public String getText(ClipData clipboard) {
    if (clipboard != null && clipboard.getItemCount() > 0) {
        return clipboard.getItemAt(0).coerceToText(getApplicationContext()).toString();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: veras el problema es que mi clipdata lo esto generando en la clase  MyTouchListener 
y lo quiero recuperar en mi clase MyDragListener, y el clip data en esta clase me lo esta recuperando "DragEvent event" el primer elemento de mi clip data osea "a" lo obtengo con esta linea "event.getClipDescription().getLabel().toString()"
pero no se con que linea accedo al segundo elemento de mi clip data osa "b"

Comment: Para obtener tu clipdata, usa: ClipData clipData = event.getClipData(); y en el aplicas la respuesta de @Jorgesys pero pasando el index que deseas